# How does count() work in sql in a group by statement

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, summary, summarization

In the following:

```
proc sql;
    create table example as
    select type, sum(var1)/count(*) as s1, sum(var2)/count(*) as s2, sum(var3)/count(*) as v3
    from dataset
    group by type;
quit;
```

will the count(*) in the select statement be the total records, or the records within each value of "type"?

Answer (score 3):

All aggregating functions (`sum`, `count`, `avg`, `max` etc') are calculated per group.
If the query does not contain a `group by` clause, then the entire result set is considered as a group (the single group in the query).

This means that given the following table:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    grp int,
    col int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
(2, 1), (2, 2),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)
```

This select statement:

```
 SELECT grp, COUNT(*) As [Count(*)]
 FROM @T 
 GROUP BY grp
```

Will result with:

```
grp Count(*)
1   3
2   2
3   3
4   1
```

And this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As [Count(*)]
FROM @T
```

Will result with:

```
Count(*)
9
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/OPGM48820)

Answer (score 2):

**The count(*) in the select statement will give the Count of records within each value of "type"**

Like

```
Table
    id name
    1  a
    2  b
    3  b
    4  a
    5  c

Select Count(*) From Table Group By name;
Output> 2
        2
        1
```

Explanation

```
As a and b is having 2 count and c is having 1
```

Another Example

```
Create table test(
id int,
name char(30)
);
insert into test
values(1,'a'),(2,'a'),(3,'b'),(4,'b'),(5,'c');

Select SUM(id)
from test
group by name;
Select '---------------';
Select count(*)
from test
group by name;
Select '---------------';
Select SUM(id)/count(*)
from test
group by name;
Select '---------------';
Select SUM(id)/(Select count(*) From test)
from test
group by name;

output>
3
7
5
---------------
2
2
1
---------------
1.5000
3.5000
5.0000
---------------
0.6000
1.4000
1.0000
```

If you want all record count

```
proc sql;
    create table example as
    select type, 
           sum(var1)/(Select Count(*) From dataset) as s1, 
           sum(var2)/(Select Count(*) From dataset) as s2, 
           sum(var3)/(Select Count(*) From dataset) as v3
    from dataset
    group by type;
quit;
```

Comment: The first statement seems wrong. First it does not match the format of the original query since the `type` variable was not included in the select list.   I guess some DBMS might give the count of the number of groups but in SAS you will still get the counts per value of `type`, even without include `type` in the variable list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get the row count for each Type. Your calculation here is the same as using the `avg()` aggregate function.

Example:

```
data work.have;
input Salary_Group $ Value;
datalines;
Group1 100
Group1 100
Group1 100
Group1 100
Group2 20
Group2 20
;
run;

proc sql;
create table example as 
select Salary_Group , sum(value)/count(*) as sum_by_count , avg(value) as average
from have 
group by Salary_Group;
quit;
```

Output:

```
Salary_Group=Group1 sum_by_count=100 average=100 
Salary_Group=Group2 sum_by_count=20 average=20
```